# While dividing two measures in DAX, How can I get a SUM of the measure to display correctly? The divide function doesn't work for me

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a DAX formula that i have used:

`Price = DIVIDE([Sales Amount], [Net Sales Quantity])`

My issue is that the SUM of Price is dividing the totals of Sales Amount and Net Sales Quantity instead of displaying the SUM of Price correctly.

Here's an example of what i see in Power BI:

| Product Code | Sales Amount | Net Sales Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AIU | 70 | 10 | 7 |
| JID | 36 | 6 | 6 |
| DII | 10 | 5 | 2 |
| TOTAL | 116 | 21 | 5.5 |

As you can see above, the total for Price is not adding up column, instead its dividing the totals for Sales Amount and Net Sales Quantity which is 116/21 = 5.5

The actual result that I need is:

| Product Code | Sales Amount | Net Sales Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AIU | 70 | 10 | 7 |
| JID | 36 | 6 | 6 |
| DII | 10 | 5 | 2 |
| TOTAL | 116 | 21 | 15 |

As you can see, its simply adding up the Price and SUM for the price is correct.

I'm new to power bi, i've looked at documentation and have not been able to solve this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **Column** instead of **Measure**

[image]